# Apache Lucene Search - Fails for Keyword - IN

Tags: lucene

Am Using Apache Lucene Search with my java application. The Query is built on Searching a name of a Person(alphabet) with the Country Code(normally represented as two letter word, Example - IN - India, US - USA, UK- England etc)

However the problem arises, when i try to search value with the Query Condition as Alphabet="Steve" and Country="IN", the search query results no values, even though the record exists, only when country is choosen as IN(India)

```
alphabet = alphabet.trim() + "*";
query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, searchFor[0], analyzer).parse(alphabet.trim());
mainQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
if ((country != null) && (country.trim().length() > 0)) {
query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, searchFor[1], analyzer).parse(country.trim());
mainQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
```

Comment: Which analyzer are you using? Some analyzers might consider IN as a stop word and therefore discard it.

Comment: Hi Emanuuele Bezzi, am using Apache Lucene Core 3.0, how to edit the StopAnalyzer,java to edit STOP WORDS, do i need to manually decompile all the class files in the jar and edit and compile?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `KeywordAnalyzer` for things such as country codes (which do not need tokenization or case/stop word folding); for people names, `WhitespaceAnalyzer` might be a good choice. `PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper` to combine both. Example:

```
Analyzer ka = new KeywordAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30)
Analyzer wa = new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30)
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper wrapper =
      new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(ka);
wrapper.addAnalyzer("countrycode", ka);
```

Now just create your `IndexWriter` using `wrapper`.

Comment: Hi, i Solved the issue by just passing a Empty Hash Set to the StandardAnalyzer.java     Set set1 = new HashSet();       
        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30,set1);